# jquery : constructed data is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I spent lot of time to figure this out but did not find anything,

```
    function constructAgenciesData() {       
        $.ajax({
           url: "getAgenciesAndGlobalJson.do",
               dataType: "json",
           success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function (index, row) { 
                  // console.log("data : "+ JSON.stringify(data));
                   $("#"+row.id).data("assignedAgencies", row.assignedAgencies).data("restOfAgencies", row.restOfAgencies).data("global", row.global).data("globalID", row.globalID);      
                  });    
                }        
         });  

   } 
   constructAgenciesData();
   $(function($){ 

      $(".globalswitch").each(function () {
         var idRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0].id;
         alert(idRow);
         console.log($('#'+idRow).data("global"));// <-- UNDEFINED
        $(this).switchButton({
            checked: row.data("global") 
        });
    });

     $(document).on('click','button.btn', function () {     
        var idRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0].id;  
        var title = $(this).parents('td:first').siblings(':eq(1)').text();
        title = "Rule Name :  " + title;
        $("#divPopUp").data('param_1', idRow);
        $("#divPopUp").data('opener', this).dialog("option", "title", title).dialog("open");
        console.log($('#'+idRow).data("global"));// <-- WORKING
        var old_array = $('#'+idRow).data("restOfAgencies"); 
        var new_array = $('#'+idRow).data("assignedAgencies"); 
        addCheckbox(diff(old_array,new_array));

    });


    });
```

I don't know why the same line :

```
console.log($('#'+idRow).data("global"));
```

is undefined in the `.each` function.

BUT it is working in the click function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$.ajax` call is asynchronous. This means that it is firing request while the rest of the `Javascript` is being run.

The `success` function within `constructAgenciesData()` might not have been completed prior to the IIFE `$(function($){`.

Therefore, there is no guarantee that the `.data('global')` will be set by the time you're trying to access it within the `$(".globalswitch").each` loop.

A solution to this issue would be to wrap the `$(".globalswitch").each` loop within a function `globalSwitchLoop()` and fire that on the success of the `$.ajax` call.

Also, take a look at [`jQuery's promises`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/).

Comment: But why we can read .data('global') in the second function click ?

Comment: Because the `success` function finished. That just applies a listener, but does not actually execute the click callback. I am pretty sure that if you were able to click the `button.btn` soon enough, you would get the same `undefined` error.

Comment: I just created this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mlotfi/Lok56Lxa/  , don't know why it's wrking in jsfiddle but not in my code .

Comment: did you apply my suggestion?

Comment: Phil, you are the best, I did the globalSwitchLoop(), it's working fine now.

Comment: Everything is working fine now in Chrome, but was surprised that when I try to read any .data() in internet explorer 11  for example   :     var old_array = $('#'+idRow).data("restOfAgencies");  it's always undefined.